# Java Annotations (Postconstruct and PreDestroy) on AEM/CQ5

Tags: java, osgi, aem

Is it possible to use a method with the annotations `@PostConstruct` or `@PreDestroy` on the Service class of an OSGI Bundle in AEM 6, because I am planning to create a separate bundle for the database connectivity and the way I will use these 2 annotations is to open the database connection on the `@PostConstruct` and to close the connection and to perform to commit or rollback on the `@PreDestroy`. If it is not possible are there any other way or work around on the approach that I am planning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OSGi uses a different set of annotations for handling the activation and deactivation of a bundle.

These are the `@Activate` and `@Deactivate` annotations from `org.apache.felix.scr.annotations`

For example:

```
@Component
public class Foo implements Bar {

   @Activate
   void activate(ComponentContext ctx) {
      System.out.println("Activating bundle: " + ctx.getUsingBundle());
   }

   @Deactivate
   void deactivate(ComponentContext ctx) {
      System.out.println("Deactivating bundle: " + ctx.getUsingBundle());
   }
}
```

For more information, check out the [OSGi wiki](http://wiki.osgi.org/wiki/Declarative_Services)

However, I don't think you should keep a database connection open throughout the entire lifecycle of the bundle. Just open and close it ad-hoc when you really need it.

What you should create when activating your bundle is not a connection but an object capable of building and maintaining a connection pool.

Google around for the [`DataSourceFactory` interface](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v42/org/osgi/service/jdbc/DataSourceFactory.html)

Also, I think AEM already provides a set of JDBC connectors OOTB. Be sure to check the [Adobe documentation on the subject](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/jdbc.html) before diving into developing a custom solution.